Unable to make text style adjustments in the Search Results template
I am trying to style my text in the search results template, but can't find where to make those adjustments. I've looked at several tutorials, and they all show results being output in the block editor enabling the administrator to make adjustments in the visual editor.
However, I don't see any results being output in my block editor. Can text style adjustments be made only with a sample output, or is there another method?


Generally there should be a "Styles" tab in the inspector for the block. Perhaps your theme has disabled all of the features, in which case WordPress would not render the tab... though it's kind of strange that the other settings for the Title block are also missing there. Have you tried switching themes to like Twenty Twenty Four to see if that might be the case?
